# how to variable in bp-custom.php in my plugin

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

This is the code in bd-custom.php

```
global $bp_profile_field_data;
function show_profile_field()
{
    $args = array(
        'field'     => 'Field Name',
        'user_id'   => 1
    );

    $tx_profile_field = bp_profile_field_data( $args );
 };
```

but i want to use this string in a plugin but it echo empty space

Comment: Please explain more you issue. Do you mean this function bp_profile_field_data( $args ) return empty?

Comment: yes it returned empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you get the string from the database
     `$matric = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT value FROM wp_bp_xprofile_data WHERE field_id = 2 AND user_id = 3");
// this variable holds the string
$matric->value`